# New reputation graph line chart option?

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph

I like the slickness of the new reputation graph, but I would still like a line or area chart that shows accumulated reputation over time.

If it makes programming easier, I think there is no problem at all with using a block line or block area chart. That way you could just change the numbering to be accumulation and then remove the spacing between bars. Should be very simple to have another chart like that and I think it makes more sense, at least for lower activity users.

Answer (score 5):

Check out your [Stack Exchange Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/da75c154-30e7-4899-a8f0-bbf5a31702f2?tab=reputation) page.  You can find the graph you are looking for there.

Comment: How do you get to this profile page for another user?

Comment: The hyperlink leads to a 404 page.

Comment: @BryanField You go to someone's profile, click activity, click network profile in the upper right corner and click the reputation tab. That's how.