# Add an option to show cumulative score on the reputation graph

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, reputation-graph, network-profile, total-reputation

I have membership and over 200 points in an increasing number (>12) of Stack Exchange sites.

I like the graph that shows all the various lines for each different site -
https://stackexchange.com/users/315778/michael-durrant?tab=reputation

But I would like an option to see the line for the *cumulative* total score (so not "[New reputation graph line chart option?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86089/new-reputation-graph-line-chart-option)" - at least not the *answer* given).

My Stack Overflow score line is at a fairly constant angle but it would be fun to see an *overall* total *line* which would be much more upward curved and additional motivation to use the site.

I tried the suggestion in Chrome in developer mode and we finally got it working, thanks to some extra effort by jmort253 -thanks man!

[image]

Comment: Hey Michael, if you're looking for the total reputation score across all sites, try this StackApp: http://stackapps.com/questions/2575/stack-exchange-reputation-graph-total-reputation-overlay I think that's what you're looking for. I'm using Chrome, and I can now see my total on this page: http://stackexchange.com/users/265671/jmort253?tab=reputation. (Note: You need the app installed to see your score)

Comment: nah, although interesting, it seems like that has the overall total as a figure.  I was actually looking for a graph that shows that changing over time., i.e. a 'combined' line graph.

Comment: Not sure I understand. That one does show your rep changing over time. I hope I didn't confuse you with some earlier comments I made with some other links. (I deleted those! So you may want to check that stackapp again...

Comment: Here is the one I deleted: http://stackapps.com/questions/2202/reputation-graph It shows how it changes over time in each individual site.  I think I get what you're asking for.  You want the line graph, but for all sites combined... Maybe balpha could add that in...

Comment: yes, the total 'all sites' accumulated score (1 line) over time.

Comment: Tried again to get this to work but non joy. Looks like it has to be a chrome script and now chrome are not allowing any url for doing that. has to go thru their store. bummer

Comment: Hi Michael, in the Tools->Extension page in Chrome, click the "Developer Mode" checkbox, then you can drag the script and drop it directly into the Extensions page and install it manually. There might be an easier way, but that's what I've been doing. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I tried that, but, see screenprint, can't pick it, even in development mode.

Comment: Hi Michael, looks like you've clicked on "Load Unpacked Extension". Don't do that. ;)  Instead, use the nautilus program to find the Userscript, then literally drag and drop the thing right dead center into the Chrome "Extensions" window. Make sure you drop it in the center, in the content area, not in the address bar. I created a [video that demonstrates the installation process](http://youtu.be/gddtaM0__dU).

Comment: finally got it working (w/out video but thx hugely).  Some indication of the drag and drap from the chrome folks would have helped (jigsaw piece perhaps).  then visit the site as normal and visit the rep page/  Will post pic above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While not quite as good as having it implemented natively, I thought this was a pretty nifty idea and went ahead and added it to [my userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2575/stack-exchange-reputation-graph-total-reputation-overlay). In addition to the overlay in the top left corner, users of the script will also have an option to toggle the "Network Total" reputation series on and off. For convenience, the toggle setting is persisted in local storage.

Example of the script in action:

[image: network reputation graph with userscript's "Network Total" series enabled]

Comment: got it working - note, it shows up when you visit the so site itself (once installed as an extension).

Comment: Oh, great! It seems I missed your update to the question yesterday, so glad you were able to sort it out. Let me know if you run into any more issues with the script.

Comment: yeah got it working and then i was cleaning up our comments.  Just accepted too.  and posted my graph!

Comment: It doesn't work when you have one "big" account and a bunch of "little" accounts.