# Add a graph showing total reputation plus major "events"

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph

My favorite game in highschool (ever?) was Age of Empires II. I still remember that awesome graph at the end (which I spent embarrassingly long amounts of time studying and marvelling at):

[image]

I know we already have a cumulative reputation graph on our https://stackexchange.com/ profile (as documented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86089/new-reputation-graph-line-chart-option)), but I'd like to see it on all of my profile pages along with daily changes and site-specific badges, etc. For example, I'd like to see the date I earned my [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag badge. Or perhaps a cluster of Nice Answer badges during that particularly productive week (that I might have some day). I'd also like to see when I earned each privelege (ability to edit posts!).

If we had something like this, I'd probably spend embarrassingly long amounts of time studying and marvelling at it.

(Bonus: easy fraud detection!)

In all seriousness, something more like this, but with the badges, etc., inserted in there somewhere:

[image: New York City Weather Chart 2003]
(Source: http://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=00014g)

Comment: "If we had something like this, I'd probably spend embarrassingly long amounts of time studying and marvelling at it." And that's why it's a bad idea. They want you to spend that time answering questions.

Comment: This is a neat idea. Everyone spends time studying their habits, so I don't think it would change that, it would just make it more efficient and fun.

Comment: @DanielFischer - "Cyborg - start answering some questions or I'm going to deny you access to that graph!" "Sorry mod."